# CSS make image fill available width

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

i got 3 images next to each other, wrapped in a div which can be resized using min-width and max-width.

the left and right image have a fixed width/height.

the center image should fill the available space depending on how wide the outer div is.

what i got so far:

```
  <div id="orangeheader" style="min-width:750px;max-width:1140px;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
    <img src="images/header_left.gif" width="220" height="150" border="0" alt="" style="float:left"/>
    <img src="images/header_middle.gif"  height="150" alt="" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="images/header_right.gif" width="275" height="150" alt="" style="float:right" />
  </div>
```

maybe this should be solved with a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fwiw, i went with a table solution:

```
<table style="border-padding:0;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:none;width:100%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
<tr>
<td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;width:220px;"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/header_left.gif" style="width:220px;height:150px;border:0" alt=""></a></td>
<td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;"><img src="images/header_middle.gif" style="width:100%;height:150px" alt=""></td>
<td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;width:275px;"><img src="images/header_right.gif" style="width:275px;height:150px" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i say this is impossible.

but blow code Partly does:

```
  <div style="min-width: 750px; max-width: 1140px; overflow: auto; width: 100%;" id="orangeheader">
    <img width="220" height="150" border="0" style="float: left;" alt="" src="images/header_left.gif">
    <img height="150" style="float: left; max-width: 645px; min-width: 255px; width: 30%;" alt="" src="images/header_middle.gif">
    <img width="275" height="150" style="float:right" alt="" src="images/header_right.gif">
  </div>
```

you can give `percent %` width to right and left so.

also you can use pattern for middle image. http://pattern8.com/ 
hope helps.

Comment: thanks but the percent is variable depending on how wide the outer div currently is

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<table style="border-padding:0;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:none;width:100%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;width:220px;">
      <a href="index.php">
        <img src="images/header_left.gif" style="width:220px;height:150px;border:0" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;">
      <img src="images/header_middle.gif" style="width:100%;height:150px" alt="">
    </td>
    <td style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;spacing:0;border:0;width:275px;">
      <img src="images/header_right.gif" style="width:275px;height:150px" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```